# How to access EWS `UniqueId` field in Outlook plugin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchangewebservices

We have a VSTO Outlook plugin using the .net Interop wrapper (v15) that adds additional metadata to emails, which we then pull into our primary application via EWS. We identify emails in our application with the `EmailMessage.Id.UniqueId` field. New functionality requires our Outlook plugin to be able to match the email currently open to the record in our application, ideally without completely re-architecting the way we identify emails in our application :) Is there any way to access the EWS UniqueId field in Outlook? I can see the `_MailItem.ConversationID` and `_MailItem.EntryID` fields but even after converting hex strings -> base64 they don't match (and are the wrong length). Googling this I've found references to a `ConvertId` function but this seems to be EWS functionality, I need something within Outlook I can call.

Comment: Did you find any way to do that ? Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can convert between `PR_ENTRYID` (exposed through `MailItem.EntryID` in OOM) and EWS id using the ConvertId operation - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/convertid-operation

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but that ConvertId operation appears to be the EWS API I mentioned in my question? I haven't checked if it works in practise but it feels pretty wrong for the Outlook plugin to be calling it's own EWS back-end, is there no Outlook plugin API that exposes it?

Comment: No, there is no client side API to convert the ID. You need to use EWS for that. Note that your EWS side can store the EWS id as one of a extended properties, which you can retrieve from your addin.